# Chart with unscaled y-values

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts, mschart

I'm trying to figure out if  I can find any exist chart in winforms C# application.

I have several integer inputs a, b, c... and at the end of processing I got  results with wide range of  values like 12, 342, 445879 etc.

On chart I want to see only hierarchy from higher size to lower without equivalent scale distance between higher and lower line ends.  Just stairway by downward curve for each input.

So two things is needed, if some kind of such chart tool is already exist, is a sorting of sequence from higher to lower with names attached to the lines and  non-scaled value display in the ratio between each other.

For example I have inputs:

```
int a = 12989;
int b = 324;
int c = 23;
int d = 12;
int e = 3;
```

and second process results:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 25;
int c = 1;
int d = 4;
int e = 14;
```

I have tried to use different graphs in list of VS,

```
 private void Size(int a, int b)
    {
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("a1", a);
        this.chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY("a2", b);
    }
```

but seems like I need different thing.

Here is desired results:

[image: unscaled columns]

Comment: Why did you reverty my clarifying descripition??? The right image is hardly the desired result?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

For x-values there is in fact a `Series` property `IsXValueIndexed` to enforce an unscaled display. There is no such thing for the y-values, though.

(The reason is probably that unscaled y-values are **not really useful**, as they will arguably **mislead the user** about the data..(..which may or may not be true of x-values; x-values containing, say, zip codes or other IDs **should** be displayed unscaled!))

To workaround you need to set the x and y-values to a count value and `set` the `Labels` of each `DataPoint` **explicitly** to the actual values you have.

Example:

[image]

```
// create an odered list of data:
List<double> data = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) data.Add(rnd.Next(100) * rnd.Next(i * 5));
data = data.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();

// now add with dummy x and y-values:
Series s = chart1.Series[0];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    int p = s.Points.AddXY(i, data.Count - i);   // dummy values
    DataPoint dp = s.Points[p];
    dp.Label = data[i] +"";        // real value, formatted
    dp.Tag= data[i];              // real value

}
```

To get rid of the axes, which can't show ay meanigful values, disable them:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

More styling:

```
s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth","15");
s.Color = Color.DarkSlateGray;
```

Note the as the y-values are really just dummies, if you need to access them, you will have to use the `Labels` and convert them from string to number type. Also note that if they are `double` or `floats` those strings will either be terribly long or formatted to a short string. To preserve the actual values you can store these additionally in the `Tag` field of each `DataPoint`..